# Remove field not working as expected

Tags: jquery-ui, textfield

I have a code that adds or removes fields when clicked, but when i bound it in a c:foreach tag, it shows unexpected behaviour, as instead of showing a remove field it shows an add field with textfield when i load the data from backend?

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    var max_fields      = 10; //maximum input boxes allowed
    var wrapper         = $(".input_fields_wrap"); //Fields wrapper
    var add_button      = $(".add_field_button"); //Add button ID

    var x = 1; //initlal text box count
    $(add_button).click(function(e){ //on add input button click
        e.preventDefault();
        if(x < max_fields){ //max input box allowed
            x++; //text box increment
            $(wrapper).append('<div><input type="text" name="parameter_value" size="50" style="width: 50%;; margin-left: 3%;" class="headers " value="${workflow.parameter_value}" />&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="#" class="remove_field bttn">Remove</a></div>'); //add input box
        }
    });

    $(wrapper).on("click",".remove_field", function(e){ //user click on remove text
        e.preventDefault(); $(this).parent('div').remove(); x--;
    });
});
</script>


<table>
<tr>
<td class="tbody_color">
                <div class="input_fields_wrap">
                    <c:if test="${not empty workflow.workflowParametersList}">
                        <c:forEach var="paramValue" items="${workflow.workflowParametersList}">
                            <input type="text" name="parameter_value" size="50" style="width: 50%;; margin-left: 13%;" class="headers" value="${paramValue.param_value}"></input>
                            &nbsp;&nbsp;<button class="add_field_button bttn">Add Parameters</button>
                        </c:forEach>
                    </c:if>
                    <c:if test="${empty workflow.workflowParametersList}">
                        <input type="text" name="parameter_value" size="50" style="width: 50%;; margin-left: 13%;" class="headers" value=""></input>
                        &nbsp;&nbsp;<button class="add_field_button bttn">Add Parameters</button>
                    </c:if>
                </div>                          
            </td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have Add Parameters button insted of Remove in your c:forEach tag which displays backend data.
Change this to:

```
        <c:if test="${not empty workflow.workflowParametersList}">
            <c:forEach var="paramValue" items="${not empty workflow.workflowParametersList}">
                <div>
                    <input type="text" name="parameter_value" size="50" style="width: 50%;; margin-left: 13%;" class="headers" value="${paramValue}"></input>
                    &nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="#" class="remove_field bttn">Remove</a>
                </div>
            </c:forEach>
        </c:if>
```

Comment: What this will do is it will remove all the fields instead of its corresponding field.